# How to access javascript variables from cpp through qml

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I've got a project which consists of several QWidgets which each has its own qml file. Each qml file imports the same Global.js file with some variables (for example var xyz = 1). Now, I want to change this javascript variables through my c++ code.

Global.js:

```
.pragma library
var xyz = 300;
```

my.qml:

```
import "Global.js" as Global

Rectangle {
    property int m_heigth
    width: Global.xyz
    heigth: m_heigth
}
```

c++:

```
this->setProperty("m_heigth", 300);   // <--- does work
this->setProperty("Global.xyz", 300); // <--- does not work :(
```

How can I access this javascript variable in C++?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a JS setter and getter function, you can call JS functions from C++, provided they are member functions of a QML object.

Comment: Is this possible without changing the qml files? I don't want to change all the qml files which also includes other qml files which includes the Global.js, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your object in `C++`, inheriting `QObject` using `Q_PROPERTY` for each of the elements you want to access from `QML`.

You then make this object visible to `QML` using `QQmlContext::setContextProperty()`.

For example, assuming `Globals` is the type of the `C++` object, your `main()` method might look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext() -> setContextProperty("globals", new Globals);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now from within `main.qml` you can access any property as follows:

```
Text {
    text: qsTr("Test")
    color: globals.myFavouriteColour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do that by having a C++ object with the respective variables as properties, exposing it via `setContextProperty()` and then accessing that object in `Global.js`

It is generally a good idea to have global state in C++ as that even survives a reload of the QML content, which is very nice for rapid development, etc

The C++ object just needs to be derived from `QObject` and use Qt`s`Q_PROPERTY` mechanism, roughly like this

```
class MyGlobal : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int xyz MEMBER m_xyz NOTIFY xyzChanged)

signals:
    void xyzChanged();

private:
    int m_xyz;
};
```

Expsoing the object looks like this

```
// assuming a QQmlEngine named engine, e.g. from a QQuickView or a QQmlApplicationEngine
MyGlobal global;
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("_global", &global);
```

The object can then be accessed in QML like if it where a QML element with the id `_global`, e.g.`var xyz = _global.xyz` or `width: _global.xyz`

Comment: Sounds good. Can you please give me some code snippets for better understanding on how to do this?